# Firefox plugin that remembers upload source directory with a finer grain than per website

Tags: facebook, firefox

When I upload a file from Flickr, I choose the file from a directory (let's call it DirectoryFlicker) of my local computer. The second time I will want to upload a file to Flickr, Firefox will have remembered which directory I uploaded from last time.

That's good, but not enough.
I want Firefox to remember several locations for the same website.

In particular for Facebook I upload from 3 different directories depending on what I am doing:

- uploading a personal picture to my timeline
- uploading the banner for an event page of a particular Facebook group
- uploading an image to a particular Facebook page I manage

Is there a Firefox plugin that can do this?

I am open to any option, for instance it could let me "remember this directory" for "this URL" or "this URL prefix" or "pages related to this Facebook group", etc.

Free, ideally open source.